# access webservice from .net ,throws error

Tags: .net, web-services

When accessing a cgi web service ,it throws the error [there is an error in xml document(]
this error happens only If the return paramater is an array of objects

how to resolve this?

------------execption details---------------
 System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="There is an error in XML document (1, 452)."
  Source="System.Xml"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at MyWebService.CallMyMethod(String hostName, String YourAppMyApptoken, Int32 subscription_id) in D:\Samjog\Temp Project\ProxyTest\ProxyTest\MyWebService.cs:line 93
       at ProxyTest.Form1.btnListFeeds_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Samjog\Temp Project\ProxyTest\ProxyTest\Form1.cs:line 209
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ProxyTest.Program.Main() in D:\Samjog\Temp Project\ProxyTest\ProxyTest\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
       Message="Cannot assign object of type System.Int32 to an object of type MyAppWSDLSubscribedFeedInfo."
       Source="dz-gayew"
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMyWebService.Read19_CallMyMethodResponse()
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer14.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       InnerException:

Answer (score 2):

If the XML is really malformed, the only thing I can suggest is getting the response as XML and then parsing it manually. It may just be that the .Net serialization does not fully understand its format.

Comment: can you give little more info on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, getting that error consuming a Delphi WebService with a .NET client.
I have to get this response

```
  <message name="CreateCustomerResponse">
    <part name="CustomerCode" type="ns1:TFHOCustomerCode" />
    <part name="return" type="xs:int" />
  </message>
```

.NET have a problem deserializing that custom data type. 
Changing to

```
  <message name="CreateCustomerResponse">
    <part name="CustomerCode" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="return" type="xs:int" />
  </message>
```

did the work and finally lost the problem. 
Hope this will be helpful for anyone, i sure lost one whole week diging for this problem.

Regards, 
Sorin

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from following Link
dont know if there is any better solution
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34950281/soap-serialization-proble.aspx